# Factoring numbers of the form $11111111$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, prime-factorization

Why $11111111$ is divisible by $73$? How can we get all the prime factors?

It is clear that it is divisible by $11$. Is there any formulae for $1111...11$ ($n$ times)? Give me some idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When $n$ is composite, you can get some factors as shown below. To get all prime factors, you can use [a computer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+11111111).

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii I want to prove it with the help of number theory.

Comment: Theory can help (as lab bhattacharjee has shown) but ultimately, prime factorization of large numbers is a job for computers (with a lot of prior human input, of course).

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii Thanks for suggestion and editing my question. i'm doing pure mathematics course so i want to use theory please don't mind.

Answer (score 9):

$$\underbrace{11111111}_{n(\ge1) \text{ digits }}=\frac{10^n-1}9$$

Now $10^8-1=(10^4-1)(10^4+1)=(10^2-1)(10^2+1)(10^4+1)$

Clearly, $73|(10^4+1)$(why?)

I think, we don't have too many clever method other than actual division to find $10^4+1=73\cdot137$

Comment: How can you say that $10^4+1$ is divisible by $73$ ?

Comment: @SiddhantTrivedi Long division?

Comment: @MikeMiller okay.

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee Can You give me reference for above formulae that you wrote first for $n\geq 1$?

Comment: @MikeMiller $$10^4+1=100^2+1=100^2+1000+25-1024=100^2+2 \cdot 100 \cdot 5+5^2-2^{10}=(100+5)^2-(2^5)^2$$

Comment: @SiddhantTrivedi, $$\underbrace{1\cdots11}_{n(\ge1) \text{ digits }}=\frac{\underbrace{99\cdots99}_{n(\ge1) \text{ digits }}}9=\frac{10^n-1}9$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Great idea!

Answer (score 4):

[The Cunningham Project](http://homes.cerias.purdue.edu/~ssw/cun/index.html) has taken as its goal the factorization of lots of numbers of the form $b^n\pm1$ for $2\le b\le12$, so in particular it covers the numbers $10^n-1$ and, by extension, $(10^n-1)/9$, the number whose decimal expansion is $n$ ones. There is a lot of information at that site about the methods used, both on the theoretical side and on the computational side.